# "Almost metric" functions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The conditions for $d:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a metric are:

**d1)** $d(x,x)=0$

**d2)** If $x\neq y$, $d(x,y)>0$

**d3)** $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

**d4)** $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

I'm trying to find functions $d$ such that $d$ does not satisfies one of that conditions, but satisfies the another three.

$d_{1}(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies d1, d3 and d4, but not d2.

$d_{2}(x,y)=1$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies d2, d3 and d4, but not d1.

Can someone give me some hints to find the other functions? Preferably I want just hints and ways to think, not the answers.

Comment: You can consider things like square roots. For example, $d(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$ is almost a metric, only failing condition 2, since $a^2 = (-a)^2$ thus $d(a,-a) = 0$.

Comment: @PhysMath That fails for not being real valued.

Comment: @WilliamElliot. Change it to $\sqrt{|x^2-y^2|}.$

Comment: Ah, good point. Then take $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, I believe this only fails condition 1

Comment: How about $\sqrt{|x-y|}$? I think that fails d4.

Comment: If you set $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=c>0$ when $x \neq y$ then you get a metric. What if you modify this so $d(x,y)=c_1>0$ when $x < y$ and $d(x,y)=c_2>0$ when $x>y$ with $c_1 \neq c_2$. Then obviously d3 breaks. Can you choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that d4 is fulfilled?

Comment: Define $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by  $d(x,y) = y - x$ when $x < y$, $0$ otherwise. An assymetric version of the standard metric..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. That will not only break d3 but also d2.

Comment: Then try one metric for $x < y$ and another for $y < x$? Break the symmetry!